# How to we can send Coupon Code For Next Order Discount in Magento 2.4.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, magento2.4, coupon

I want to send **Coupon Code for Next Order Discount**. When any customer will place an order then customer will received a **unique Coupon Code For Next Order**.

anyone have an idea how to i'll do this ?

Comment: Create event for sales order place after and write your code for coupon email